# Toggle next div from input

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to toggle the first div after the input

Is it possible?

Ive tryed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function spoiler() {
    $(this).next().show();
}
</script>

<div>
       <input value="Show/Hide" style="" onclick="spoiler();" type="button"/>
</div>
<div style="display:none;">
    Text
</div>
```

I can't use classes or ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code wasn't working because `$(this)` wasn't referencing your button. Also, `.next()` looked for the element after the button, which doesn't exist. You're looking for the element after the parent of that button.

Also, instead of binding the event using `onclick`, just bind it entirely with JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[value="Show/Hide"]').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next('div').toggle();
    });
});​
```

You can then simplify your HTML:

```
<div>
   <input value="Show/Hide" type="button" />
</div>

<div style="display:none;">
    Text
</div>​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NXM7w/**

Comment: Blender, i get your point, and it works. This it's for a forum where in the same page there are lot's of this examples so they will be triggered all at the same time using this and it's not possible...

Comment: What do you mean? This code works for any number of these elements without any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
$(this).parent().next().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use:

`$(this).parent().next().show();`

You need to traverse up the tree one place as you're inside a `<div />` already.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact location in the DOM you could do something like `$('div:nth-child(2)')` to select the element, but this will be very fragile - changes to the markup will have the potential to break your script.

Answer (score 0):

Because next() is referencing the next element in the div, not the next parent div

Use parent().next().show()

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the global variable 'this' how you are currently using it. Have your DIV pass itself and then you can work from there fairly easily:

```
<div>
       <input value="Show/Hide" style="" onclick="spoiler(this)" type="button"/>
</div>
<div style="display:none;">
    Text
</div>
```

Then your JS function can look like this:

```
function spoiler(div1) {
    $(div1).parent().next().toggle();
}
```

Hope that does it for you.